# Save an array of colors to User Defaults - iOS Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am wondering how to save an array of UIColors to user default.

I have the following code to save a single UIColor to user defaults, does anyone know how to modify this to allow me to store arrays of UIColor in NS User Defaults?

```js
extension NSUserDefaults {
    
    func colorForKey(key: String) -> UIColor? {
        var color: UIColor?
        if let colorData = dataForKey(key) {
            color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(colorData) as? UIColor
        }
        return color
    }
    
    
    
    func setColor(color: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
        var colorData: NSData?
        if let color = color {
            colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(color)
        }
        setObject(colorData, forKey: key)
    }
    
}
```

- I am using Swift 2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in following way

```
let colors = [UIColor.whiteColor(), UIColor.greenColor()] // Array of colors
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(colors), forKey: "ColorsKey") //For saving in NSUserDefaults
//For retrieving use following 
let decodedColorsData  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ColorsKey") as! NSData
let colorsArray = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(decodedColorsData) as! NSArray) as Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2: Saving and loading colours / colours to user defaults
note: the load from defaults works but contains a deprecated item which does not yet have a good worked example to replace it.

```
               let colorToSetAsDefault : UIColor = view.backgroundColor!
                do
                {
                    let data : NSData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: colorToSetAsDefault,requiringSecureCoding: false) as NSData
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "userHeadingColor") // your key in quotes
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                } // end of do
                catch
                {
                    print("Couldn't save color")
                }  // end of catch

            // load the color back as a test to make sure the save has worked
            if let colorObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userHeadingColor")
            {
                let colorData = colorObject as! NSData
                let color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData as Data) as? UIColor
                // replace with unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:
                self.testDefaultsView.backgroundColor = color
            }
            else
            {

            }
```

Comment: Been searching for a solution to this...alas, no luck.

Comment: Just add `toHex` & `fromHex` facilities/properties/init in a `Color` and/or `UIColor` extension, then store as JSON/YAML/CSV i.e. String type.